# Pre sign-up lambda function in cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

When creating a new cognito user, I would like to confirm their account through the Pre Sign-up lambda. It looks as follows:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Confirm the user
        event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;

    // Set the email as verified if it is in the request
    if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
        event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
    }

    // Set the phone number as verified if it is in the request
    if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("phone_number")) {
        event.response.autoVerifyPhone = true;
    }

  console.info("EVENT\n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
  console.info("CONTEXT\n" + JSON.stringify(context, null, 2))
  
    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);
};
```

I cloudWatch logs I get

```
"response": {
    "autoConfirmUser": true,
    "autoVerifyEmail": true,
    "autoVerifyPhone": true
}
```

but in cognito user is not verified phone_number_verified=false, email_verified=false and user status is FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD instead of CONFIRMED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cognito does ignore pre-sign lambda when signing up of a new user is done via API call. Even though lambda is invoked response is ignored by Cognito. Registration by UI is only choice for now if lambda result shouldn't be ignored.